# Timezone - Change from EST to EDT or happens automatically?

Tags: 20.04

I currently have:

```
Current default time zone: 'America/New_York'
Local time is now:      Tue Nov 15 07:58:25 EST 2022.
```

I wonder if this time will automatically change based on EDT?
Or vice-versa?

Seems like a major problem for scripts being run on cron.

Comment: EDT change to EST already occurred in the USA on 2022-11-06. On that day, there were many questions on AskUbuntu, but none regarding the time change, nor broken scripts caused by the time change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't mess with `systemd-timesyncd`, your machine will adjust automatically.

And from `cron` manpage:

> **Daylight Saving Time and other time changes**
>
> Local time changes of less than three hours, such as those caused by
> the start or end of Daylight Saving Time, are handled specially. This
> only applies to jobs that run at a specific time and jobs that are run
> with a granularity greater than one hour. Jobs that run more frequently are scheduled normally.
>
> If time has moved forward, those jobs that would have run in the
> interval that has been skipped will be run immediately. Conversely,
> if time has moved backward, care is taken to avoid running jobs twice.
>
> Time changes of more than 3 hours are considered to be corrections to
> the clock or timezone, and the new time is used immediately.

So no need to worry, the developers of `cron` were clever enough to implement this.